# How to access properties in interface typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, observable

Hi I want to access the property inside the interface from observable.

I have two properties inside this interface.
loan-grade.ts

```
export interface LoanGrade{
    grade:string
    subgrade: string
}
```

I use subscribe to access Observable<LoanGrade[]>.
edit.component.ts

```
grades: LoanGrade[];
ngOnInit():void{
    this.termGradeServie.termGradeData$.subscribe(grades=>{
     this.grades = grades; 
  })
}
```

Then in my html I want to print out all the grades that exist from observable I got. But I cannot do item.grade. How can I do this?
edit.component.html

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of grades">
   <tr>
       <td><span>{{item.grade}}</span></td> 
   </tr>
</ng-container>
```

I think the problem is that when I subscribe termGradeData$ it returns observable(LoanGrade[]) so I can't help myself to set `this.grades` as LoanGrade[]. But if I set it to LoanGrade[], I cannot access the property of grade or subgrade.

Comment: Can you share a log of what you get from subscription?

Comment: So if I do console.log(grades) inside subscribe, I get
(8) [{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}]
  0: {grade: 'A', subgrade: '1'}
  1: {grade: 'A', subgrade: '2'}
  ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service, make sure to write the observable with `LoanGrade[]` type:

```
export interface LoanGrade {
    grade: string;
    subgrade: string;
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TermGradeService {
    public termGradeData$: Observable<LoanGrade[]>;
}
```

and that somewhere in the code it gets a value (for example, by connecting it to an `http.get` method).

If you need to set a value for it by yourself, you can use 'BehaviorSubject`  as follows:

```
export interface LoanGrade {
    grade: string;
    subgrade: string;
}

const initalLoanGradesValue: LoanGrade[] = [];

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TermGradeService {

    private _termGradeData$: BehaviorSubject<LoanGrade[]> = new BehaviorSubject<LoanGrade[]>(initalLoanGradesValue);

    get termGradeData$() {
        return this._termGradeData$.asObservable();
    }

    // ...
}
```

then somewhere in the code, make sure a value is emitted through the BehaviorSubject:

```
this._termGradeData$.next([
    { grade: 'x1', subgrade: 'y1' },
    { grade: 'x2', subgrade: 'y2' },
    { grade: 'x3', subgrade: 'y3' },
]);
```

Then in your component, you can do either A or B below:

***A***

```
    private termsGradeSub: Subscription;
    public grades: LoanGrade[];
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.termsGradeSub = this.termGradeService.termGradeData$.subscribe((grades) => {
            this.grades = grades; // "pull" the grades out of the observable, and save it to a local variable
        });
    }

    // ...
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.termsGradeSub?.unsubscribe();
    }
```

and in your html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of grades">
   <tr>
       <td><span>{{ item.grade }}</span></td> 
   </tr>
</ng-container>
```

or

***B*** (preferred way of reading observables):
inside the component:

```
public termGradeData$: Observable<LoanGrade[]>;

ngOnInit() {
    this.termGradeData$ = this.termGradeService.termGradeData$;
}
```

and use the `async` pipe in your html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of grades | async">
   <tr>
       <td><span>{{ item.grade }}</span></td> 
   </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Adding `private termsGradeSub: Subscription;` made it work.  What is the logic behind that? We are not using termsGradeSub in html but just assigning it made item.grade accessible.

Comment: `private termsGradeSub: Subscription` and then `this.termsGradeSub = this.termGradeService.termGradeData$.subscribe(...` saves the subscription for you to be able to unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy (when the component is destroyed), to prevent leaking subscriptions. The code should work without it. In fact, you can omit this and it should still work. Please check again to see if you changed something else in the code that made this work, and please up-vote the answer if it helped you.